# How should I fix this git mistake?

Tags: git, github, gradle

1. I made some code changes(updates to added files)
2. Then I mistakenly removed the project level build.gradle using Git Bash:

   `rm -f build.gradle
   git commit -m "removing project level build.gradle"
   git push origin master`

My whole project directory is under git control(git init'ed), but for some reason my code changes weren't pushed to the master branch.  My build.gradle was removed though--Why?

I want to do the following now:

1. push the code changes I made from my local repo to the remote repo.
2. undelete the build.gradle
3. remove build.gradle from source control, since different people are using different gradle versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I need to ADD ANY CHANGED FILES, even if they were already added.  This was new to me because I relied on Android Studio to do this before, where it was implicit with a commit.
2. git checkout SHA_OF_COMMIT build.gradle
3. "git rm --cached build.gradle"; 
   build.gradle was already in my repo, so adding *.gradle to my gitignore would not have had any effect.  Executing the above command removes the file from git's control.  Other collaborators should run this command too to stop tracking from their local repos.